# Line break issues with 'time' and 'make'

Tags: linux, time, makefile

I am developing some software in C. One of the targets in my makefile runs a test, and I use `time` to record the runtime and `valgrind` to check for memory leaks. When I invoke one of the smaller tests directly from the command line, I get this.

```
$ time valgrind bin/test data/gff3/example1.gff3 data/gff3/example2.gff3
==27268== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27268== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27268== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27268== Command: bin/test data/gff3/example1.gff3 data/gff3/example2.gff3
==27268== 
==27268== 
==27268== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27268==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27268==   total heap usage: 4,001 allocs, 4,001 frees, 152,648 bytes allocated
==27268== 
==27268== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27268== 
==27268== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27268== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)

real    0m1.460s
user    0m1.330s
sys 0m0.110s
```

However, when I invoke the test from my makefile (using the same exact command), I get this.

```
$ make mem
time valgrind bin/test data/gff3/example1.gff3 data/gff3/example2.gff3
==27265== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27265== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27265== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27265== Command: bin/test data/gff3/example1.gff3 data/gff3/example2.gff3
==27265== 
==27265== 
==27265== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27265==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27265==   total heap usage: 4,001 allocs, 4,001 frees, 152,648 bytes allocated
==27265== 
==27265== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27265== 
==27265== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27265== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
1.32user 0.10system 0:01.55elapsed 91%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 214752maxresident)k
24inputs+8outputs (1major+18568minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

There seem to be line break issues with the output of the `time` program at the bottom, as well as some additional output I didn't see when invoking directly from the command line. I've seen this before when I'm trying to time a job I've run with `nohup`.

Why is this happening and what can I do to get consistent results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

time is a bash builtin.  The output from your Makefile looks like the output of /usr/bin/time.  The easiest way to get consistent results is to run '/usr/bin/time' instead of time on the command line.

Comment: The line endings are still weird though.

Comment: Thanks! @Tomalak If you look at the `time` man page, it showd you how you can set your own format.

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, yes. Ignore my last then. What a _bizarre_ default format string though!

Comment: @Tomalak Indeed. I like the fact that `/usr/bin/time` gives a lot more flexibility and output, but I find the default format difficult to read.